# Web Apps: Closeable Announcements/Info/Tooltip boxes

Tags: java, web-applications, tooltip

I want to understand how to implement an announcement/info box system that displays
a box for the user with information.
The user can do nothing or close the box, but then it will never be seen again.

E.g. Facebook home page. Box asking for Translators.
if you leave it then its always there.

But if you close it, it never appears again.

Does this mean that a Boolean value needs to be used and checked
for announcement/info boxes?

I'm looking for a pseudo way with database tables to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This info goes into a portal page personalization attributes table for that user.
Each portlet will have Display set  to True or False for each user.